# Задача С++. Сегментация данных

Tags: c++

Текст задачи приведён ниже. Задача со степика, ссылку на задачу оставлю ниже, т.к. нужен текстовый файл, чтобы проверять правильность решения, но его размер больше ограничения, поэтому не могу его прикрепить.

**Проблема.**

На примере приведённом к задаче все работает. Но когда я скачиваю файл данных  и проверяю на нём, то как оказалось количество строк "пар" больше , чем указано в первом параметре первой строки. По моему коду получается, что после М*2 идут адреса, которые отдельно считываются в массив, но получается что он продолжает читать эти "пары" и всё работает не так как надо. Еще как я понял ATOI() преобразует в INT, а у меня uint64_t, и мне кажется, что значения "обрезаются"(если это конечно так), что тоже влияет на задачу.

Если будете присылать код решение через контейнер MAP, то, пожалуйста, объясните поподробнее код, т.к. я еще не до конца понимаю как через MAP сделать.

Формат входных данных следующий:

в первой строке вам даны 3 числа m,q,r≥0 , где q - это количество запросов, на которые вам нужно ответить, r - физический адрес корневой таблицы страниц
следующих m строках записаны пары paddr и value - описание физической памяти, каждая пара значит, что по физическому адресу paddr хранится 64 битное значение value, при этом гарантируется, что все paddr различны, выровнены на границу 8 байт и помещаются в 64 бита
в последних q строках идут целые числа - логические адреса, которые вам нужно преобразовать в физические, для каждого из этих чисел нужно вывести на отдельной строке либо физический адрес, либо слово "fault", если преобразовать логический адрес в физический нельзя.
Считайте, что таблица страниц имеет формат 64 битного режима x86 (4 уровня, каждая страница 4 KB, каждая запись 8 байт, формат записи был показан в лекциях), но вы можете игнорировать все поля, кроме бита присутствия (на картинке бит P - нулевой бит) и собственно физического адреса.

Для всех физических адресов, не указанных во входных данных (среди m пар paddr value), считайте, что по этим адресам хранятся нули.
все физические адреса, которые хранятся в записях таблицы страниц должны быть выровнены, как минимум, на границу 4096 байт (4Kb), т. е. младшие 12 бит физических адресов всегда равны 0, соответственно, хранить младшие биты нет смысла и в записи таблицы страниц они не хранятся - их место занимают специальные флаги.
Пример: 
Sample Input:
4 4 0
0 4097
4096 8193
8192 12289
12288 16385
0
4096
42
131313

Sample Output:
16384
fault
16426
fault

**Пример моего кода** (да, да , он ужасен, не кидайте тапки:(). Ссылка на степик в самом низу.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

bitset<64> PLM4(bitset<64>);
bitset<64> NullBIT(bitset<64>);
bitset<64> Smesch(bitset<64>);
bool WordCount(string);

int main()
{
    char buff[1000];
    //char* str = new char[100];
    string str;
    uint64_t mas[3];
    /*  ofstream fout("Las_Vegas.txt");
    fout << "4 4 0\n0 4097\n4096 8193\n8192 12289\n12288 16385\n0\n4096\n42\n131313";
    fout.close(); */
    ifstream file_out(""путь"\\dataset_44327_15.txt");
    //ifstream file_out("Las_Vegas.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        file_out >> buff;
        mas[i] = atoi(buff);
    }


    uint64_t *mass = new uint64_t[(mas[0] * 2)];
    uint64_t *mas3 = new uint64_t[mas[1]];
    getline(file_out, str); cout << str;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < ((mas[0] * 2) + mas[1]); i++) {
        if (i < (mas[0] * 2)) {
            file_out >> buff;
            mass[i] = atoi(buff);
        }
        //file_out.getline(str, '\n');
        getline(file_out, str);
        //fgets(str, 100, file_out);
        if (i >= (mas[0] * 2)) {
        if (!WordCount(str)) {
            file_out >> buff;
            mas3[i - (mas[0] * 2)] = atoi(buff);
        }
        }
    }
    file_out.close();


    bitset<64> CR3(mas[2]);
    bitset<64> offset;
    uint64_t a;

    for (int i = 0; i < mas[1]; i++) {
        bitset<64> prover(mas3[i]);
        bool breakF = false;
        //offset = Smesch(prover <<= 36);
        for (uint64_t j = 0; j < (mas[0] * 2); j = j + 2) {
            if (((CR3 | offset = PLM4(prover)).to_ulong() == mass[j]) || breakF) {
                for (int u = 1; u <= 4; j += 2, u++) {
                    bitset<64> pr(mass[j + 1]);
                    a = (pr = NullBIT(pr)).to_ulong();
                    a = ((pr = NullBIT(pr)) | (offset = Smesch(prover <<= (9 * (u - 1))))).to_ulong();
                    if (u == 4) {
                        bitset<64> prover(mas3[i]);
                        a = (offset = Smesch(prover <<= 38)).to_ulong();
                        cout << (pr.to_ulong() + a);
                    }
                    else
                        if (!(a == mass[j + 2])) {
                            cout << endl << "!!!" << "fault" << "!!!" << endl; j = j - 2 * (u - 1); breakF = true; break;
                        }//if SECOND

                }
                if (!breakF) { j = j - 6;  breakF = true; }
                break;
            }
            else { cout << endl << "!!!" << "fault" << "!!!" << endl; }
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}



bitset<64> PLM4(bitset<64> bit)
{
    bit <<= 15;
    bit >>= 53;
    return bit;
}

bitset<64> Smesch(bitset<64> bit)
{
    bit <<= 15;
    bit >>= 53;
    return bit;
}

bitset<64> NullBIT(bitset<64> bit)
{
    bit >>= 12;
    bit <<= 12;
    return bit;
}

bool WordCount(string str)
{
    int space = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            space++;
        }
    }
    if ((space + 1) > 1) { return true; } else
    return false;
```

### }

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

bitset<64> PLM4(bitset<64>);
bitset<64> NullBIT(bitset<64>);
bitset<64> Smesch(bitset<64>);
bool WordCount(char []);

int main()
{
  char buff[1000];
    //char* buff = new char[1000];
    char* str = new char[100];
    uint64_t mas[3];
    /*  ofstream fout("Las_Vegas.txt");
    fout << "4 4 0\n0 4097\n4096 8193\n8192 12289\n12288 16385\n0\n4096\n42\n131313";
    fout.close(); */
    ifstream file_out("C:\\Users\\Nikita\\Desktop\\dataset_44327_15.txt");
    //ifstream file_out("Las_Vegas.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        file_out >> buff;
        mas[i] = atoi(buff);
    }

    uint64_t *mass = new uint64_t[(mas[0] * 2)];
    uint64_t *mas3 = new uint64_t[mas[1]];

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < ((mas[0] * 2) + mas[1]); i++) {
        if (i < (mas[0] * 2)) {
            file_out >> buff;
            mass[i] = atoi(buff);
        }
        //file_out.getline(str, 100, '\n');
        //fgets(str, 100, file_out);
        if (i >= (mas[0] * 2)){ 
            file_out >> buff;
            mas3[i - (mas[0] * 2)] = atoi(buff);
        }
    }
    file_out.close();


    bitset<64> CR3(mas[2]);
    bitset<64> offset;
    uint64_t a;

    for (int i = 0; i < mas[1]; i++) {
        bitset<64> prover(mas3[i]);
        bool breakF = false;
        //offset = Smesch(prover <<= 36);
        for (uint64_t j = 0; j < (mas[0] * 2); j = j + 2) {
            if (((CR3 | offset = PLM4(prover)).to_ulong() == mass[j]) || breakF) {
                for (int u = 1; u <= 4; j += 2, u++) {
                    bitset<64> pr(mass[j + 1]);
                    a = (pr = NullBIT(pr)).to_ulong();
                    a = ((pr = NullBIT(pr)) | (offset = Smesch(prover <<= (9 * (u - 1))))).to_ulong();
                    if (u == 4) {
                        bitset<64> prover(mas3[i]);
                        a = (offset = Smesch(prover <<= 38)).to_ulong();
                        cout << (pr.to_ulong() + a);
                    }
                    else
                        if (!(a == mass[j + 2])) {
                            cout << endl << "!!!" << "fault" << "!!!" << endl; j = j - 2 * (u - 1); breakF = true; break;
                        }//if SECOND

                }
                if (!breakF) { j = j - 6;  breakF = true; }
                break;
            }
            else { cout << endl << "!!!" << "fault" << "!!!" << endl; }
        }
    }

    //system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}



bitset<64> PLM4(bitset<64> bit)
{
    bit <<= 15;
    bit >>= 53;
    return bit;
}

bitset<64> Smesch(bitset<64> bit)
{
    bit <<= 15;
    bit >>= 53;
    return bit;
}

bitset<64> NullBIT(bitset<64> bit)
{
    bit >>= 12;
    bit <<= 12;
    return bit;
}
/*
bool WordCount(char str[])
{
    int space = 0;
    bool DVA = false;
    for (int i = 1; i <= strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            space++;
        }
    }
    if ((space + 1) >1) { DVA = true; }
    return DVA;
}

*/
```

***Ссылка на задачу:***
https://stepik.org/lesson/44327/step/15?unit=22137

Comment: `Для всех физических адресов, не указанных во входных данных (среди m пар paddr value), считайте, что по этим адресам хранятся нули.` Может быть из-за этого количество пар больше чем указано в первом параметре первой строки?

Comment: я сдал эту задачу, всё там хорошо - в примере сначала записано `m,q,r`, потом в `m` строках пары `paddr` `value`, потом в `q` строках запросы на вычисление физического адреса по логическому адресу.